# Contraction and $\max$ function

Tags: uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions, dynamic-programming, contraction-operator

$f: \Bbb R \mapsto  \Bbb R$

$g:  \Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb  R$

$h:  \Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb  R$

$h:=\max\{f(x), g(x)\}$

Is $h$ a contraction on $ \Bbb R$ if $f$ and $g$ are both so?

*First attempts of mine -although they are not very fruitful- is the following:
since every contraction mapping is Lipschitz cont's and hence uniformly cont's, and I just proved that $h$ is uniformly cont's if $f$ and $g$ are so, $h$ could be a contraction if $f$ and $g$ are so.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are both $L$-Lipschitz continuous, i.e.
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L |x-y|,
\quad
|g(x) - g(y)| \leq L |x-y|,
\quad \forall x,y,
$$
and let us prove that $h$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous too.
(The required result follows with $L < 1$.)

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
To fix the ideas, suppose that $h(x) = f(x)$ (the case $h(x) = g(x)$ is similar).
Since $h(y) \geq f(y)$, we have that
$$
h(x) - h(y) = f(x) - h(y) \leq f(x) - f(y) \leq L |x-y|.
$$ 
A similar argument shows that $h(y) - h(x) \leq L |x-y|$, so that
$|h(x) - h(y)| \leq L|x-y|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be contractions. Now, the proof given by Rigel assumes that they are both L-Lipschitz although question does not indicate as such. For all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. We have,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M_1 |x-y|$$
$$|g(x)-g(y)|\leq M_2 |x-y|$$
for some $M_1, M_2 \in (0,1)$. Set $M=max \{M_1,M_2\}$.
Now, assume without loss of generality that $h(x)=f(x)$. We have two cases:

1. If h(y)=f(y), then we clearly have the result as $f$ is a contraction.
2. For the case of h(y)=g(y), consider the subcase $f(x)\geq g(y)$. Then,
   $$|h(x)-h(y)|=|f(x)-g(y)|=f(x)-g(y)\leq f(x)-f(y) \; (since \; g(y)\geq f(y))$$
   $$\leq |f(x)-f(y)|\leq M_1|x-y|\leq M|x-y|$$
   Showing that $h$ is a contraction. Proof for the other sub-case is similar.